# Exception thrown for INSERT statement (Hibernate HQL) using DISTINCT

Tags: hibernate, hql

I try to perform bulk insert with below insert statement in Hibernate 4.3.6 / 4.3.7

```
INSERT INTO TransAttrDO (
    custCode,
    partNo,
    custAttrType,
    qtyUnit,
    createServer
)

SELECT 
    DISTINCT pp.vendorCode,
    pp.partNo,
    'PT',
    pp.qtyUnit,
   'myhost'
FROM PalletPartInfoDO pp
WHERE pp.orderNo = 'SI-HKG-00000001'
```

I get the exception below.

```
15:41:22,542 ERROR ErrorCounter:78 - <AST>:8:32: unexpected AST node: DISTINCT
15:41:22,542 ERROR ErrorCounter:73 - <AST>:8:32: unexpected AST node: DISTINCT
<AST>:8:32: unexpected AST node: DISTINCT
at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.SqlGeneratorBase.selectColumn(SqlGeneratorBase.java:1975)
at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.SqlGeneratorBase.selectClause(SqlGeneratorBase.java:544)
at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.SqlGeneratorBase.selectStatement(SqlGeneratorBase.java:186)
at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.SqlGeneratorBase.insertStatement(SqlGeneratorBase.java:440)
at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.SqlGeneratorBase.statement(SqlGeneratorBase.java:153)
at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.exec.BasicExecutor.<init>(BasicExecutor.java:63)
at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.buildAppropriateStatementExecutor(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:580)
at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.doCompile(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:222)
at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.compile(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:158)
at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.HQLQueryPlan.<init>(HQLQueryPlan.java:126)
at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.HQLQueryPlan.<init>(HQLQueryPlan.java:88)
at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.QueryPlanCache.getHQLQueryPlan(QueryPlanCache.java:167)
at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSessionImpl.getHQLQueryPlan(AbstractSessionImpl.java:301)
at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSessionImpl.createQuery(AbstractSessionImpl.java:236)
```

When I remove `DISTINCT` keyword, it inserts records successfully. If I executes the select statement with `DISTINCT` without insert, it works fine.

Can anyone help?

Comment: are you using `createSQLQuery` method?

Comment: I use createQuery() method and then executeUpdate() to run the query